# How insert multiple string values on single node in builtin LinkedList type in mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, linked-list

I'm newbie in this field.

I have a table called comment. And i want to get multiple column data and multiple rows. Like I row-1 has two columns.

Can I use Linked List to pass data from controller to view?If so how should I  do that. If not than how should I pass data from controller to view. I know `ViewBag`, `Session` etc. But they are no help to me.

When I run this code it gives me following exception

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

How should I code in controller and view too. Will there be a connection of this with model too?

Please if you have some source link about How to use LinkList in MVC4 Asp.Net, please do share.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Controller
***>

```
Comment CommentObj = new Comment();
try
{
  var query = from comment in db.Comments
  from TeachOb in db.TeacherAccounts
  from StdOb in db.StudentAccounts
  select new
  {
    CommentBy = comment.UserID,
    CommentOn = comment.PostID,
    CommentContent = comment.CommentContent,
    TeacherName = TeachOb.TeacherName,
    StudentName = StdOb.UserName
   };
   LinkedList<string> getData = new LinkedList<string>();
   LinkedListNode<string> Node = new LinkedListNode<string>("");
   foreach (var Info in query)
   {
     if (Info.CommentOn == PostID && Info.CommentBy == Loggedinuser)
     {
       string commentBy = Info.CommentBy.ToString();
       string commentOn = Info.CommentOn.ToString();
       string commentContent = Info.CommentContent.ToString();
       string teacherName = Info.TeacherName.ToString();
       Node.Value = commentBy;
       Node.Value = commentOn;
       getData.AddFirst(Node);
      }
     Session["list"] = getData;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exp)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
  }
```

> Blockquote
>   ***This my View***
>   Blockquote

```
@foreach (var std in Session["list"] as LinkedList<string>)
{
 <li>
  <a href="#">
    @std.ToString();
  </a>
  <br /><br />
  </li>
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If yes then share your code.

Comment: I have... but i don't know how to share code here..

Comment: Edit your post and paste your code below the description of your problem.

Comment: I have done it now.

Comment: debug your code check are you getting Session["list"] value or not?

Comment: No... It gives this error.An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_at4lgmo3.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this may be this will help.

```
 foreach (var Info in query)
{
    if (Info.CommentOn == PostID && Info.CommentBy == Loggedinuser)
    {
        string commentBy = Info.CommentBy.ToString();
        string commentOn = Info.CommentOn.ToString();
        string commentContent = Info.CommentContent.ToString();
        string teacherName = Info.TeacherName.ToString();
        Node.Value = commentBy;
        Node.Value = commentOn;
        getData.AddFirst(Node);
        }
}

if(getData!= null)
{
     ViewBag.ListData = getData;
}
```

View Blog

```
@foreach (var std in ViewBag.ListData)
{
 <li>
  <a href="#">
    @std.ToString();
  </a>
  <br /><br />
  </li>
 }
```

Comment: @foreach (var std in Session["list"] as LinkedList<string>)
                                {
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            @std.ToString();
                                        </a>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    </li>

                                }

Comment: When it reaches session["list"] as LinkedList<string> it gives an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: No it still gives exception